# Povray rendering of Jmol visualization appears brighter

Tags: molecular-modeling, visualization-software

I would like to use Povray to render nice-looking graphics of molecules, which can be exported from visualization softwares like Jmol. However, I have noticed that the color of the rendered graphics looks brighter compared to the visualization in Jmol itself. (see image below) Is that something expected? And is there a way to adjust the brightness so that the brightness remains the same as in Jmol?

[image]

P.S. <strike>After some investigation, I believe I have located the cause of the problem (but have still not resolved it yet, see images below): In the render preference, there is a "Gamma" option which controls the brightness of the rendered image, but no matter what value I put in here, the value of Gamma in the final rendering window is always 2.5, which is too high (it should be ideally around 1). I would really appreciate it if someone could suggest how to correct this behavior. **This problem appears with Povray 3.8 on MacOS.**</strike>

Seems that the brightness has nothing to do with the Gamma value after all (tested with Povray 3.7), so the problem remains.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I use the following options and everything ran fine: +SP8 (start with every 8th pixel), +Q8 (quality is high), +A0.3 (anti aliasing), Antialias=On, Antialias_Threshold=0.3.

Comment: @Camps May I ask where do you add these options? Is it in the command line? (sorry I'm not an expert in Povray)

Comment: I am not an expert either. I add such parameters inside a file called par.ini, then, from Jmol console, after loading my system, I wrote: write POVRAY file.pov. Finally, from the Linux prompt: povray par -Ifile.pov -Ofile.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the answer myself: simply adding the line

```
global_settings { assumed_gamma 2.0 }
```

in the *.pov file makes all the difference:

[image: Jmol + povray after gamma correction]